# Multiple TableViews horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to display multiple UITableView pages in a horizontal scrollView. I have tried to make multiple view controllers and add them as children to the main one. But the delegate of the tableView is throwing an error: found nil when unwrapping an optional value. Any Alternative solution about how can i implement this? And i want the scroll view indicator up and not down too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I suggest to use collectionView instead of scrollView, each cell of the collectionView should be a container to your UItableViews.

[This article](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) describes how you can add collectionViews in tableView cells, I know it is the opposite of your case, but I believe it should helps you referring to how you can handle the delegation for each tableview.

Hope it helped.